# microsoft teams get conversation link

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft team integration using nodejs. In the Teams client you can easily copy a link to the conversation and this can be used to navigate to the specific conversation any time.

see the screenshot for the reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fog3ojddcb6mdis/screen%20shot%202021-02-10%20at%202.44.31%20pm.png?dl=0

Is there a way to get this link in the botframework when the conversation is created? I have seen there are deep link apis for group chat etc. which requires the list of users to be provided.

but I am interested in obtaining the conversation link that appears on client.

This one is not useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

The activity object I get in nodejs on starting a conversation is:

```
{
  "localTimestamp": "2021-02-13T05:42:25.313Z",
  "timestamp": "2021-02-13T05:42:25.313Z",
  "type": "message",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "from": {
    "name": "Stacy",
    "id": "29:1a-Xb7uPrMwF2XqjMEHCC7ytV2xb2VUCqTA-n_s-k5ZyMCTKIL-ku2XkgbE167D_5ZbmVaqQxJGIQ13vypSqu-A",
    "aadObjectId": "718ab805-850c-43ec-8d4e-4af0c543df75"
  },
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
  "conversation": {
    "isGroup": true,
    "conversationType": "channel",
    "id": "19:a0a0088174a644cb91406f4d8f79d888@thread.tacv2;messageid=1613194945273",
    "tenantId": "04e934f3-0866-4a6d-b07c-a4737e8f9865"
  },
  "localTimezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "recipient": {
    "name": "MyBot",
    "id": "28:a835cf1d-83a8-5ae9-845a-23a68a1df442"
  },
  "id": "1613194445273",
  "channelData": {
    "channel": {
      "id": "19:a0a0088174a644cb91459f4d8f79d888@thread.tacv2"
    },
    "tenant": {
      "id": "04e930f3-0866-4a6d-c07c-a4737e8f9865"
    },
    "team": {
      "id": "19:774d4103fe51420db1437130378b196e@thread.tacv2"
    },
    "teamsChannelId": "19:a0a0088174a644cb91409f5d8f79d888@thread.tacv2",
    "teamsTeamId": "19:774d4103fe51420db1437190478b196e@thread.tacv2"
  },
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "text/html",
      "content": "<div><div><span itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.skype.com/Mention\" itemid=\"0\">MyBot</span> opty&nbsp;</div>\n</div>"
    }
  ],
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "entities": [
    {
      "text": "<at>MyBot</at>",
      "mentioned": {
        "id": "28:a835cf1d-83a8-4ae9-845a-23a68a1df432",
        "name": "MyBot"
      },
      "type": "mention"
    },
    {
      "country": "US",
      "platform": "Mac",
      "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
      "locale": "en-US",
      "type": "clientInfo"
    }
  ],
  "text": "opty"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) Graph API

**POST**: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats`

These permission needs to be given at delegated level to the Application
`Chat.ReadBasic`, `Chat.Read, Chat.ReadWrite`

You can will be able to see chatType/Topic base on that you can get the chatId and pass it to [Get Message in Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http),
So in the end you can use the deep link and create deep link to chat using
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-a-chat

**Note**: While creating deep link to specific message in group chat, you should have the group chat id and message id. Message Id you can get it within Bot activity and use it later to create deep link.

Comment: how about at the time when conversation is creating in the nodejs which extends the TeamsActivityHandler class. here onMessage gets all the messages. Can something be done to generate the URL at this point?

Comment: at that time you need to have the group chat id can capture the message id and use deep linking for the same

Comment: Hope this is helpful, You can accept the answer so it will be helpful for others as well

Comment: definitely giving a try first

Comment: i have updated my question with the activity object I get in nodejs. Can you please advise what pieces I need from it to for chat API?  also what info would I need from chat API that is not here?

Comment: You can use the message id from turnContext but for group chat you will require the chat id which you can fetch through the Get Chat API

Comment: Thanks! Though once i have group id and message id, I do not see any API to generate the deeplink using this information. I am seeing API that requires all user ids rather group id. any thoughts?

Comment: i am interested as well. any advise please?

Comment: @Vik, if you have team id and message id for channel message deep linking or i would say chat id or message id for chat message deep link, you can make a call Get channel message API or Get Chat message API they will give you webURL in response which is exact deep link URL to teams message you can use it anywhere

Comment: Sorry to hijack this thread. i do have chat id, team id and message id as these are coming in activity. The part that is not clear is which specific API can give the weburl ?  i don't see any API which only requires message or chat or team id to give the URL. plz advise

Comment: Check these Graph API available here : [Get Message in Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) and [message in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I have checked both of these and I do not see the webURL field in the sample responses on these pages. What I am missing?

Comment: Can you try to form teams deep link URL using message id and chat or team id something like https://teams.microsoft.com/chatid/messageid

Comment: https://teams.microsoft.com/19:774d4103fe51420db1437190378b196e@thread.tacv2/1614006604094 does not work. gives a page not found error.

Comment: You can try this one al the required fields you will be having with you API call
[https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/{channelid}/{messageid}?groupId={groupid}&tenantId={tenant id}]

Comment: were you able to create deep link using the above URL?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to do deep linking to an existing group chat, you'd need to have the chatId.
The URL is as follows:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/{chatId}/0?tenantId={tenantId}
```